# Save RSS Feed in database Sqlite for Iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, rss, sdk, feed

I am creating a small application rss for iphone
I wanted to make sure that once you are parsing the XML feeds were stored in a SQLite database so when you open the application should not wait for the reloading of feed (which by then will Bottene upgrade) but are read by database.
you have any advice for me to do this?
I can not save the parsed data in the database :(

tnx

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question that can be answered easily since it's **very** broad; basically it's a whole application design process. To get you started, here are the logical steps needed:

1. Design your database layout according to your needs
2. Create that database in/for your app
3. Load the XML feed
4. Parse the XML data
5. Insert the parsed data into your database
6. Make your app read data from the database
7. Make your app display parsed data
8. Have your app periodically load and parse the XML feed

These are 8 steps all requiring a certain degree of understanding. If you're stuck on one step, learn how to achieve it; when you're still stuck, ask a specific question. I hope this helps!